# php error - don't know how to fix it

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm really bad at PHP. So, yes, this code is simplistic. But I'd rather get this code working if possible. Thank you.

**Purpose of PHP Code**

There are technically two fields, male and female genders. I am trying to trigger a statement, assuming that if a person picks 0 for both, to tell them fill one of them, otherwise, if empty, to fill it in, otherwise, to test it via `test_input` function which is at bottom.

What I keep getting is an error that consistently says this:

`PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')'` in regards to the first line of the PHP code. I've raked over the code so much but can't figure out how to fix it.

**PHP Code**

```
   if ((($_POST["male"]) === "") && ($_POST(["female"]) === "")) {
     $quantityErr = "pls fill in one of the genders";
   elseif (empty($_POST(["male"])) 
    $maleErr = "# of people (gender male) required";
   else 
     $male = test_input($_POST["male"]);
 }
```

**HTML Field Code**

```
       <div class="field">
          <label>* Number of People</label>
          <select class="ui dropdown" name="male">
            <option value="">Gender Male</option>
            <option <?php if ($male === 0 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="0">0</option>
            <option <?php if ($male == 1 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="1">1</option>
            <option <?php if ($male == 2 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="2">2</option>
            <option <?php if ($male == 3 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="3">3</option>
            <option <?php if ($male == 4 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="4">4</option>
            <option <?php if ($male == 5 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="5">5</option>
            <option <?php if ($male == 6 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="6">6</option>
            <option <?php if ($male == 7 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="7">7</option>
            <option <?php if ($male == 8 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="8">8</option>
            <option <?php if ($male == 9 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="9">9</option>
            <option <?php if ($male == 10 ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="10">10</option>
          </select>
          <?php if(isset($maleErr)) print ('<span class="error">* ' . $maleErr . '</span>'); ?>
          <?php if(isset($quantityErr)) print ('<span class="error">* ' . $quantityErr . '</span>'); ?>
        </div>
```

**Test Function**

```
function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}
```

Comment: This `$_POST(["female"])` is incorrect. You can use `{}`s or `[]`s to access array values. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: @chris85, how is it incorrect? I've looked at the code till I'm blue. Probably fatigue, but can't see it.

Comment: Should be `$_POST["female"])` See the extra `(` you have there? it would probably be easier to use empty.

Comment: so, it should be this: `((($_POST["male"]) === "") && $_POST(["female"])) === "")`

Comment: No, no `(` after `$_POST`. Probably easier to write it as `if (empty($_POST["male"]) && empty($_POST["female"])) {` Oh but I guess `0` is a valid value?

Comment: @chris85, it is a valid value because not everyone will check in with both genders ... hence why I'm checking for several stuff 1) if both are 0, please fill in one, etc ...

Comment: Okay well then check the `''` but don't put a `(` after `$_POST`; That is an array.

Comment: Please, especially if you are unsure of the language, use an editor with decent syntax checking - there are numerous free ones that would catch all these daft syntax mistakes

Comment: @chris85, should it be this? `if (($_POST["male"] === "0") && $_POST(["female"] === "0"))`, if not, could you write it out as it should be b/c clearly I'm not catching it very well ... sorry.

Comment: Success, no success?

Comment: @chris85, sorry, ftp is crazy slow. it takes forever to upload a single file. it's only from this location. it drives me bonkers ...

Comment: @chris85, also, just kinda realized something. doesn't `empty` equals '0' regardless? so, even if a person wanted to say '0' for legitimate purposes, doesn't this script prevent that?

Comment: Empty did/does but according to your message you don't allow that, right? `# of people (gender male) required` I wouldn't consider `0` a number of people. I thought that was expected behavior and you just didn't want to it to be non-set.

Comment: @chris85, sorry for miscommunication on my part. i do want to allow the option of '0' being set if a female wants to say only females are checking in, and no males, and vice-versa.

Comment: Okay, logic is a bit off. I'll post update in 20ish minutes, quick game.

Comment: @chris85, please take your time. I really appreciate your help. at this point, i'm wishing this whole thing is just over. anyway. thank you.

Comment: Remote died. Update posted. This should put you in a place where you can take it (I also didn't test it but I think that is correct).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
$_POST(["female"])
```

is incorrect to access the `female` value of the `POST` [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Curlys `{}` or brackets `[]` can be used to access arrays.

> Both square brackets and curly braces can be used interchangeably for accessing array elements (e.g. $array[42] and $array{42} will both do the same thing in the example above).

This should be correct:

```
if (empty($_POST["male"])  && empty($_POST["female"])) {
     $quantityErr = "pls fill in one of the genders";
} elseif (!empty($_POST["male"]) && $_POST["male"] > 0) { 
     $male = test_input($_POST["male"]);
} elseif (empty($_POST["male"])) {
    //male is not set or equal to 0; if male is 0 then female >= 1 and set. logic doesn't have any female checks so unclear currently how you want to handle that
    $maleErr = "# of people (gender male) required"; // maybe add message that it is required to be greater than 1.
}
```

You also had incorrect conditionals. When using `{}`s on control structures you need to close the control block. Your `elseif` wasn't closing the previous `if`.

Comment: Just noticed missed one more of those incorrect accessing of POST array.

Comment: just saw your update. testing it now. ftp slow!

Comment: I'm still having issues, but I've accepted your answer b/c it helped a bit and I'll hopefully figure out the rest. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you have written incorrect syntax

try this

```
 if ((($_POST["male"]) === "") && ($_POST["female"] === "")) {
     $quantityErr = "pls fill in one of the genders";
   elseif(empty($_POST["male"]))
    $maleErr = "# of people (gender male) required";
   else 
     $male = test_input($_POST["male"]);
 }
```

Comment: that triggered this error: `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_ELSEIF`

Comment: Oh ! i have corrected syntax.

Comment: that still triggered the same error in regards to third line of your code, the elseif part.

Comment: you need to remove extra space before elseif and start bracket.